# Standard Linux command to get the complete path including user and hostname

Tags: linux

I am looking for standard command, if any, to produce the same effect as :

> echo $USER@`hostname`:`pwd`

I have both local and remote terminal open, on remote terminal I would like to use this command and copy/paste the path for using with  `scp` command. This could be seen as an extension of `readlink -f`, which in addition to absoulte local path, also adds hostname and user.

**I am not looking for how to create alias to this effect**, my interest is in knowing if there is an standard command for this.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a standard bash command to do what you want to do. You could write your own bash command, here is a link how to: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/84686/how-to-create-custom-commands-in-unix-linux

Inside your commandfile you could write the following to archive what you want to:

```
echo $USER@$HOSTNAME:$PWD
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to add a function like this into your `.bashrc`

```sh
netlink ()
{
    echo $USER@$(hostname -f)\:$(readlink -f $1)
}
```

I'm using zsh with ohmyzsh and I also add

```sh
netlink_clipcopy ()
{
    echo -n $USER@$(hostname -f)\:$(readlink -f $1) | clipcopy
}
```

in this way I already have the link into the clipboard